# How to add new tables to flask-sqlalchemy database after database init?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have launched [this project](https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server) and it uses Flask-SQLAlchemy and already has some classes (tables). Now I added few more tables - classes that inherit `db.Model`. And when I run application, I get this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'table_name' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.`

I also opened and inspected the database file, but there is no such table created, so error seams a bit misleading.

How to achieve that newly defined classes be created as tables in database?

Comment: The error is not telling you that the table exists in the database. It is telling you that your `MetaData` instance (in Python) already holds meta data for a table.

Comment: Where can I find that `MetaData` instance and clear it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Python cache files. I deleted all `__pycache__` folders that I found in my project directory and it helped.